# Creating an image of an unallocated flash drive (Data Recovery)

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, data-recovery, flash

I've got a flash drive given to me by my teacher to "fix", since plugging it into a windows Machine didn't do anything for her. It has some assignments and basically text-based data.

Partition manager shows 3.7GB unallocated space (it's a 4GB drive), though Windows Explorer says "Please Insert a disk into Drive H:".

I then fired up Kali and tried to make an image of the drive. But dc3dd only outputs till the "command line: *dc3dd if=...*", and nothing after that.

As far as I'm aware, dc3dd can be used to image unallocated space as well. I'm considering creating a FAT32 partition, just so I can then proceed to use a data recovery tool to get back as much as I can. What would be the least harmful way to do so?

Comment: Could always try recuva to retrieve files.

Comment: "What would be the least harmful way to do so?" Do you mean to recover the files from the image or to actually make the image?

Comment: I mean formatting the drive so that a recover application can try and recover files. It is currently completely unallocated.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to do data recovery, its not necessary to do a disk image of the usb driver. It appears the partition table on the USB has corrupted, therefore that is why its not showing up correctly. You could try attempting to rebuild the partition table, which GParted does and highly recommend try doing first. Or you can use a data recovery program.

I suggest using EaseUS to attempt recovery of the data if you don't want to use gparted, and then store what files you recovered and reformat the usb drive. If you create a new partition like you are saying, you run the risk of not being able to recover data, as creating a new partition will overwrite data which could also be files you are trying to recover.
[EaseUS](http://www.easeus.com/data-recovery/partition-recovery-software/free-usb-drive-partition-recovery-software.htm)

Comment: Unfortuantely even EaseUS is unable to recover the partition. I guess I'll boot into Kali later and try gparted as well.

Comment: Suggesting not to image in a data recovery situation is very bad advice, honestly. Making s bitstream copy is the first step to ensure any recovery attempt does not make the situation worse.